# Is 51Degree supported in Sitecore 8.2?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, 51degrees, sitecore8.2

Before I start to jump into setting up device detection for Sitecore there is two option available 51Degree and Sitecore device detection service.

I've used 51Degree for Sitecore 7.5 but not able to find any information related to the latest version of Sitecore i.e 8.0 on wards.

Are they still supporting Sitecore ? or discounted?

Thanks

Comment: Sitecore switched to usage of netbiscuits. But if you depend on high-level Sitecore API then almost nothing should be changed to you. You shouldn't worry what is under the hood.

Comment: This would be better asked of 51Degrees and/or Sitecore, not Stack Overflow. We do programming questions here, not support contracts.

Comment: The reason for asking this question here is because if anyone been using 51Degree on latest sitecore then it would be good to get their thoughts and opinions where as support will try to convince to purchase the product.

Answer (score 1):

I consider this a software architecture question...

There are a couple of GitHub repos around, but I would suggest 
[3Chillies Device Detection for Sitecore 8](https://github.com/3chillies/Sitecore-Device-Detector)

The foundation of Sitecore is .net, and with the pipeline available you should in theory be able to extend anything. Like Anton said, most of the core api's have not changed.

> QUOTE: The initial version of this extension forked the Mobile Device Detector originally created by Alexander Doroshenko. The upgrade includes support for 51Degrees version 3.2 and Sitecore 8 onwards. It has not been tested with Sitecore versions prior to 8.

I have not found a 'out of the box' solution. But maybe this is a good place to start.

Comment: This would be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: 3Chillies is slightly outdated but will still work with the latest 51Degrees data file and dll. It's worth adding as of version 9 we are integrated in Sitecore.